# How to reverse a dll and call its functions?

Tags: disassembly, debuggers, dll, patch-reversing

I have got a `custom.dll` which is utilized in a larger application. The application executable imports this dll to use its functionality. But this functionality is not used through out the life cycle of the application but only when a specific event occurs. for instance when I input something in the application console a new thread would be created and some of the functionality of the given dll would be used. Now the problem is I am unable to find out what is exactly going on in the dll without having that application executable. I only have the dll file. I want to reverse it. Just like debugging an exe file and go through the registers step by step to find out what is what and why something happens, simply perform a dynamic analysis on the dll instead of the static one.

**To be more specific**, the dll file creates a specific string, I want to know how that string is created and where it is stored for console usage.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [OllyDbg's loaddll.exe](http://www.ollydbg.de/Loaddll.htm) to load a DLL and call (and debug) its functions:

[image: loaddll]

Comment: How should I know functions arguments without even having them reversed?

Comment: You'd probably want to reverse engineer them with IDA Pro to find out how many arguments they take, what the argument types are, etc.